# VRP: How to guide the first solution strategy without accumulating costs?

Tags: or-tools

**Setup and Goal:**

I want to solve a vehicle routing problem with time windows and optional stops. I am looking for a solution that serves as many stops as possible. There is no need to minimize arc costs, I am only interested in the number of serviced stops. For each stop I have defined a cost for not servicing it. I define the cost of an arc (i,j) to be the transit time in seconds because I my understanding is that this is useful in problems with time windows.

**Problem:**

The arc costs interfere with the penalties for dropping stops. The solver might drop a stop because getting there is too expensive. But I don't care about the cost of getting to a stop.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Multiply the stop drop penalties by a large number so that is much more expensive to drop a stop than to travel between stops.
2. Remove the arc cost from the objective function but keep the arc cost available for the first solution strategy.

**Question**:
Is 2) possible in or-tools? What's the best practice for guiding the first solution strategy but not accumulating costs in doing so?

Comment: If you don't care about the arc cost, do not add it to the model.

Comment: Sure, but the first solution strategies are less efficient if the arcs have no cost. In the time window setting, it is useful to explore nearby stops first. Right? Efficiency is important to my setting since I have about 2000 stops.